# React Hooks useRef initialization issue, useRef only works on subsequent calls

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am implementing useRef into my project. I have a form that has clickable sections. Once clicked it opens the form. I'm using Reactstrap Collapse to show/hide the form. I need to be able to open the form and show the section that needs to be filled out, however the scrollIntoView once I click the section doesn't work until I open and close the form again. I'm stumped. I `console.log(formRef)`, the ref returns as expected of the component that I want to be scrolled to the top of viewport on subsequent calls. My guess would be that the `formRef` is being initialized as `null` to begin with so initial calls to the ref do not work. However, once it knows the ref the subsequent calls work. I'm not sure how to go about this..

If I need to provide an example that is stripped please let me know. I am expecting this to be just an initialization issue.

**Form**

```
import React, { useRef, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  FormQuestionsContext,
  FormAnswersContext,
  ExpandedSectionContext,
} from "../../Store";
import SectionHeader from "../SectionHeader";
import ImageUploader from "../CommentsSection";
import Ratings from "../Ratings";
import { Collapse, Button, CardBody, Card } from "reactstrap";
import FontAwesome from "react-fontawesome";
import styles from "./bedthreeform.module.css";

function BedThreeForm({ Name }) {
  const formRef = useRef(null); //useRef Initialization
  const [expandedSection, setExpandedSection] = useContext(
    ExpandedSectionContext
  );
  const [formQuestions, setFormQuestions] = useContext(FormQuestionsContext);
  const [formAnswers, setFormAnswers] = useContext(FormAnswersContext);
  const array = formQuestions.bedthree;
  const onChange = (e, name) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setFormAnswers((state) => ({
      ...state,
      [Name]: { ...state[Name], [name]: value },
    }));
  };

  //! The function I use when I want to tell useRef to scrollIntoView
  const handleOpen = () => {
    expandedSection === Name
      ? setExpandedSection("")
      : setExpandedSection(Name);
    formRef.current.scrollIntoView();
  };

  const answeredQuestions = formAnswers.bedthree
    ? Object.keys(formAnswers.bedthree)
    : null;
  console.log(formRef);
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        className={styles["CollapseBtn"]}
        onClick={handleOpen} //Calling the function here
        style={
          answeredQuestions &&
          answeredQuestions.length === formQuestions.bedthree.length
            ? {
                color: "white",
                ":focus": {
                  backgroundColor: "#02BD43",
                },
                backgroundColor: "#02BD43",
                marginBottom: "1rem",
                width: "100%",
              }
            : answeredQuestions &&
              answeredQuestions.length !== formQuestions.bedthree.length
            ? {
                color: "white",
                ":focus": {
                  backgroundColor: "#bd0202",
                },
                backgroundColor: "#bd0202",
                marginBottom: "1rem",
                width: "100%",
              }
            : {
                ":focus": {
                  backgroundColor: "#fafafa",
                },
                marginBottom: "1rem",
                width: "100%",
              }
        }
      >
        <p>BEDROOM #3 INSPECTION</p>
        <FontAwesome
          className="super-crazy-colors"
          name="angle-up"
          rotate={expandedSection === Name ? null : 180}
          size="lg"
          style={{
            marginTop: "5px",
            textShadow: "0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
          }}
        />
      </Button>
      <Collapse
        className={styles["Collapse"]}
        isOpen={expandedSection === Name}
      >
        <Card>
          <CardBody>
            {array ? (
              <div>
                <SectionHeader title="Bedroom #3 Inspection" name={Name} />
                <div
                  ref={formRef}
                  className={styles["BedroomThreeFormWrapper"]}
                  id="bedroom-three-form"
                >
                  {array.map((question, index) => {
                    const selected =
                      formAnswers[Name] && formAnswers[Name][question]
                        ? formAnswers[Name][question]
                        : "";
                    return (
                      <div className={styles["CheckboxWrapper"]} key={index}>
                        <h5>{question}</h5>
                        <Ratings
                          section={Name}
                          question={question}
                          onChange={onChange}
                          selected={selected}
                        />
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
                {!answeredQuestions ? (
                  ""
                ) : (
                  <Button
                    onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                    style={
                      !answeredQuestions ||
                      (answeredQuestions &&
                        answeredQuestions.length !==
                          formQuestions.bedthree.length)
                        ? {
                            backgroundColor: "#bd0202",
                            color: "white",
                            pointerEvents: "none",
                          }
                        : {
                            backgroundColor: "#02BD43",
                            color: "white",
                            pointerEvents: "none",
                          }
                    }
                  >
                    {!answeredQuestions ||
                    (answeredQuestions &&
                      answeredQuestions.length !==
                        formQuestions.bedthree.length)
                      ? "Incomplete"
                      : "Complete"}
                  </Button>
                )}
                <br />
                <ImageUploader name="bedthree" title={"Bedroom #3"} />
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div></div>
            )}
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BedThreeForm;
```

[CodeSandbox Stripped Form](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-albattani-nc337?file=/src/App.js) Doesn't work as expected, however that is the stripped code.

**Update** I'm open to suggestions to bypass this, or an alternative way to do this. I'm not sure why it only does it on subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these lines:

```
         <CardBody>
            {array ? (
                ...
                <div
                  ref={formRef}
                  ...
```

This (virtual) dom will be evaluated only if `array` is defined. In case you would like to have your `formRef` always to point to the dom, then You'll have to strip it out from your condition.

Comment: I took it out if the conditional statement and added it outside into an empty div. However, I still received the same output.

Comment: Are you able to push it to codesandbox? It'll be much easier to help you

Comment: I'm updating now, however the codesandbox for whatever reason isn't showing up the form correctly. However, inside is the stripped form. You could copy and paste to whatever you would like. Notice the way it changes opening and closing when you click on it and subsequently.

Comment: Look at the logs, you're getting lots of errors from reactstrap

Comment: I figured it out. I just posted the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the issue, the issue is calling it when the content in the collapse hasn't been loaded yet, Reactstrap has an attribute `onEntered` which basically when set, will run the function as soon as the collapse has fully opened. The example that I found is [here](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/collapse/). Also, by setting the attribute `innerRef` on a Reactstrap component I can manipulate it just like I could a regular component using `ref`.